# i can use this method CrossDeviceInfo.Current.Id or apple store will reject my app?

Tags: ios, xamarin

can I use this method to store the user post and activity in the device, also store the user activity in my database without login, do you think Apple will reject my application?

```
 Console.WriteLine(CrossDeviceInfo.Current.Id);
            //165CAD6D-12F2-43A4-B8A9-43DDE442C5DD
```

Comment: It just uses [`identifierForVendor`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620059-identifierforvendor) under the covers so you shouldn't have an issue.

Answer (score 0):

No need to worry, for a long time developers cannot read the real device id on iOS. The id that you get with this is a fake one so that no one can track users across all apps. But it will be consistent for your own apps so you can identify users there.